# GroupBy and transform a map based on another map in Scala

Tags: scala

I have a map as follows

```
val typeMap = Map(
"mk1" -> "m",
"mk2" -> "m1",
"mk3" -> "m2",
"mk4" -> "d",
"mk5" -> "d2",
"mk6" -> "d2",
"mk7" -> "d3",
"mk8" -> "f4"
)
```

I have another map that defines the group condition

```
val groupMap = Map(
"m_type" -> List("m", "m1", "m2"),
"d_type" -> List("d", "d2", "d3"),
"c_type" -> List("c","c1")
)
```

I need to use the conditions in the groupMap to pick the keys of typeMap whose values are mapped to the types in groupMap to get a new Map as follows

```
Map(
"m_type" -> List("mk1", "mk2", "mk3"),
"d_type" -> List("mk4", "mk5", "mk6", "mk7"),
"c_type" -> List()
)
```

Comment: and what is the relation to Apache Spark here??? It's plain Scala. That said, if you reverse both maps (and explode the second on the values) you can easily join on the keys

Comment: What if the same value is associate with multiple keys?

Comment: @UninformedUser Have made the changes you recommended. I can't follow what you meant. Could you elaborate ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `groupMap` is guaranteed to have only unique values in all lists you can create a reverse map and use it to group by `typeMap` values:

```
val reverseGroupMap = groupMap.flatMap{case (key, value) => value.map(_ -> key)}

typeMap
  .groupBy{case (key, value) =>  reverseGroupMap(value)}
  .map{case (sec, map) => sec -> map.values.toList}
```

Comment: How do I handle if I have an value in typeMap that is not a part of any List in groupMap ?

Comment: @AjaySangamithran how do you want them to be handled? is it ok to just discard them? or you can group them into `None` key via switching `reverseGroupMap(value)` -> `reverseGroup.get(value)`

Comment: @AjaySangamithran to filter you can use `.filter{case (key, value) =>  reverseGroup.contains(value)}`

Comment: @AjaySangamithran was glad to help!